# Unable to open downloaded file for flutter_downloader

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter downloader package to download files , but in my case the download complete successfully but I can't open the downloader file by click on it in notification and I can't find it in my phone's files

this is my code for this problem

```
downloadFile(url) async {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    print("the directory is :");
    print(directory.path);
    try {
      final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: url,
        savedDir: directory.path,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true,
      ).then((value) async {
        bool waitTask = true;
        while (waitTask) {
          String query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_id='" + value + "'";
          var _tasks =
              await FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(query: query);
          String taskStatus = _tasks[0].status.toString();
          int taskProgress = _tasks[0].progress;
          if (taskStatus == "DownloadTaskStatus(3)" && taskProgress == 100) {
            waitTask = false;
          }
        }

        await FlutterDownloader.open(taskId: value);
      });
      print("the task id is :");
      print(taskId);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

can anyone know the reason for this issue

note that : I had add the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (waitTask) {
          String query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_id='" + value! + "'";
          var _tasks =
              await FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(query: query);
          String taskStatus = _tasks![0].status.toString();
          int taskProgress = _tasks[0].progress;
          if (taskStatus == "DownloadTaskStatus(3)" && taskProgress == 100) {
            waitTask = false;
          }
        }
```

Replace these lines.